# MS-Access Form Visible property is being inconsistent

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, ms-access-2013, visible

My company has recently upgraded from MS Access 2013 to MS Access 365. I have about 23 databases and only 2 of them are acting up. The following code is almost exactly the same in all databases except for what happens inside the IF statement.

```
Private Sub cmbSelectProf_AfterUpdate()

gUName = [cmbSelectProf]
Call globalOfficerInfoSelection

    
    gVCredit = Val(gCredit)
    gVAdmin = Val(gAdmin)

    If gVCredit = 33 Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Main"
        DoCmd.ApplyFilter "UndQryCorp"
        DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
    Else
        MsgBox ("You have not been given CDS Maker permission.  Please contact Credit Administration")
        Application.FollowHyperlink "\\appsrv03\apps\CreditApplications\SwitchBoardMain2013_v2.accdb"
        DoCmd.Quit
    End If

Forms![officer switchboard].Visible = False
End Sub
```

The issue comes at the very end when I try to hide the [officer switchboard]. Some databases it hides it and some it doesn't. If I Debug the VBA and step through the code it will hide it without me changing anything. Below is code of a database that the Visible property does work.

```
Private Sub cmbSelectProf_AfterUpdate()

gUName = [cmbSelectProf]
Call globalOfficerInfoSelection

    gVCredit = Val(gCredit)
    gVAdmin = Val(gAdmin)
    gVOfficerID = Val(gOfficerID)

    If gRM = 2 Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "CutMain"
        DoCmd.ApplyFilter "CutMainOfficer_filter"
        DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "CutMain", acNewRec
        DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "CutMain", acNewRec
    Else
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Cutmain"
        DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "CutMain", acNewRec
    End If
    
Forms![officer switchboard].Visible = False

End Sub
```

Comment: That's too much code. It will help us if you make a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You want to avoid bang notation as much as possible. Does it work if you do it like this: `Forms.Item("officer switchboard").Visible = False`    ?

Comment: Why set focus to a form that will not be visible?

Comment: I never found out what was happening, but I put the Visible property setting at the beginning of the code instead of the end, works fine.